# Как создать программу с PyQt5 из нескольких классов?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, классы, gui

Имеется идея создания простого приложения с использованием *PyQt5*, но хочу разделить его на несколько классов, отвечающих каждый за свое дело.

Допустим, класс `Skeleton`(код представлен ниже) будет строить "скелет" программы, то есть создавать само окно, его размеры и название.

А другой класс, допустим `FormBuilder` должен бы создавать в окне, которое создал класс 'Skeleton', какую-нибудь форму и отобразить эту форму.

Но у меня не получается написать код для второго класса. Можете, пожалуйста, помочь?

**main.py**:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication


class SkeletonOfWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.build_skeleton_with_basic_settings()

    def build_skeleton_with_basic_settings(self):
        self.setFixedSize(800, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('Plates')
        self.show()


class FormBuilder:
    pass
    # ???


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = SkeletonOfWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Объясните пожалуйста лучше, для чего вам нужен класс `FormBuilder`? Что вы имеете в виду написав `формы какие-нибудь`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

я оставил вам некоторые комментарии по тексту. Если что-то будет не понятно спросите.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget, \
    QGridLayout, QPushButton, QLabel, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QTime, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont


class FormBuilder(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('FormBuilder')
        self.setObjectName('formBuilder')
        self.resize(300, 200)

        self.label = QLabel()
        font = QFont('Arial', 20, QFont.Bold)
        self.label.setFont(font)

        self.start = QPushButton("Start")
        self.start.clicked.connect(self.startTime)

        self.pause = QPushButton("Pause")
        self.pause.clicked.connect(self.pauseTime)        
        
        layoutH = QHBoxLayout()
        layoutH.addWidget(self.start)
        layoutH.addWidget(self.pause)

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addLayout(layoutH)

        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.showTime)
        self.current_time = QTime(0, 0)

    def startTime(self):                                          
        self.timer.start(1000)
        
    def pauseTime(self):                                          
        self.timer.stop()

    def showTime(self):
        self.current_time = self.current_time.addSecs(1)
        label_time = self.current_time.toString('mm:ss')
        self.label.setText(label_time)
    

class SkeletonOfWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        # https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#details
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()                         # +++
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)              # +++
        
        self.build_skeleton_with_basic_settings()
        
        # создать экземпляр класса FormBuilder
        self.formBuilder = FormBuilder()    
        # разместить объект `self.formBuilder` в менеджер компоновки        
        self.grid.addWidget(self.formBuilder, 0, 0, alignment=Qt.AlignRight | Qt.AlignTop)

    def build_skeleton_with_basic_settings(self):
#?        self.setFixedSize(800, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('Plates')
        
        # создать менеджер компоновки 
        self.grid = QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)             # +++


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = SkeletonOfWindow()
    ex.resize(800, 600)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, а почему преобразование разрешения экрана происходит в самом конце при проверке?

Comment: @GunTHE   если вы имеете в виду `ex.show()`, то показывать окно правильно тогда, когда все виджеты уже определены и размещены в менеджер компоновки. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, 
как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: я не про ex.show(), а про ex.resize(). Почему нельзя выполнить данное преобразование в функции build_skeleton_with_basic_settings? И Ваше объяснение про ex.show() тоже отличное!

Comment: @GunTHE я не говорил, что это нельзя. Просто такие вещи я делаю так, потому что мне так удобнее и понятнее.

Comment: Ясно, спасибо. Не знаю, можно ли задавать Вам кучу вопросов, но если Вы сможете ответить, то вот:
1) Заметил, что можно сделать меню. Сделал отдельный виджет для меню и делаю так:
<code>
        self.barMenu = QWidget()
        self.setMenuBar(self.barMenu)
</code>
Но ничего не работает. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: @GunTHE я вам смогу ответить практический на любые вопросы, для этого вы должны их задать,  нажав на кнопку `Задать вопрос` и сформулировать его и приложить пример того что вы пробовали сделать.

Comment: добрый день, можете, пожалуйста, подсказать, почему не работают методы resize для кнопок 'Start' и 'Pause' в Вашем коде?

Comment: @GunTHE я не понял ваш комментарий. Если у ваш есть проблемы, задайте новый вопрос. Опишите что вы хотите сделать и что у вас не получается, а также приложите пример проблемного кода.

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте использовать `Qt Designer`. Там можно создавать отдельные окна и формы, при этом они будут в разных класах. Скачать можно [здесь](https://build-system.fman.io/qt-designer-download) или [здесь](https://www.qt.io/download). Туториалы - [здесь](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/pyqt_using_qt_designer.htm) и [здесь](https://pythonbasics.org/qt-designer-python/)